# Как сделать хэндлер для неактивной формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу рисунок вывести на форму, при неактивной форме:

```
gfx = Form1.ActiveForm.CreateGraphics();
gfx.DrawImage(bmp, 0,0);
```

Эти две строчки кода говорят о том, что на активную форму попадает рисунок, но если форма неактивна, то возникает ошибка на 1-ой строке:

> В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка
> на объект.

Как такого избежать?

**update** [1](http://www.filedropper.com/testimg)
Попробовал сделать через `PictureBox,` но возник фактически тот же самый вопрос, как обратиться к объекту на форме (даже не активной) из добавленного класса?

**update** [2]

сделал маленький прототип программы, по таймеру (10 сек) на форму выводится картинка (не визуально пока), вот код исходников:

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testimg
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            doimg pic = new doimg();

            pic.picture();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
     }
}
```

doimg.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace testimg
{
    class doimg
    {

        public void picture()
        {

            // some staffs to get a picture, so it's in bmp object now.
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200, 200,    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            gfx = Form1.ActiveForm.CreateGraphics(); // works well with active form
            gfx.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);

        }

     }
}
```

Собственно говоря сам архив проекта доступен по этой ссылке: [testimg.rar](http://www.filedropper.com/testimg)

Если форма будет активной 10 сек то все проходит гладко, но если же форма неактивна то получим ошибку. Как решается данная проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ActiveForm` — это **любая** активная форма приложения в данный момент времени. Вы уверены, что вам нужно выводить рисунок на **любую** активную форму? Видимо, вам нужно порисовать в какой-то определенной форме — так и рисуйте непосредственно в ней.

Если же вам действительно нужно рисовать на **любой** активной данный момент форме, то этого никак не избежать, кроме как показать на экране какую-то форму. Но опять же, мне не ясна цель.

Также, если у вас MDI приложение, то активная форма получается по свойству `ActiveMdiChild`.

Comment: да вот в том-то и дело что мне нужно вывести рисунок на **конкретной неактивной форме**, поэтому и хэндлер более точный нужен.

Comment: Передавайте в `doimg` ссылку на форму (в конструктор или в метод). А в методе `picture()` обращайтесь к переданной форме, а не к статическому свойству `Form.AciveForm`.

`       private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // так
            doimg pic = new doimg(this);
            // или так
            pic.picture(this);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Судя по MSDN ([Form.ActiveForm Property](https://sites.google.com/site/gibekm/programming/nemerle/asyncawait)) свойство ActiveForm статическое, а, значит, такого кода, который написан в запросе просто быть не может. Скорее всего у Вас вот такой код:

```
gfx = Form.ActiveForm.CreateGraphics();
```

Не обращайтесь к статическому свойству, раз из вопроса следует, что рисунок нужно вывести на конкретной форме:

```
gfx = Form1.CreateGraphics();
gfx.DrawImage(bmp, 0,0);
```

Comment: да в том-то и дело что это подключаем класс, т.е. в таком случае: `Ошибка 1 Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateGraphics()" требуется ссылка на объект` нету такого метода там.